# Taking Dictionary output from Linq statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

This is my entity collection.

```
Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>> EntityCollection = new Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>>();
```

When I receive value in `EntityCollection`, I want to filter it.

```
var filtered = from entity in EntityCollection
                       where entity.Key == entityId
                       select entity.Value;
```

Now I want only `entity.value`.
So I created a variable:

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> entityDetails = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

How can I cast `filtered` to `entityDetails`?

I tried with `filtered.ToList<Dictionary<string, string>>`, but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get directly from `Dictionary` instead of using LINQ like yours:

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> entityDetails = EntityCollection[entityId];
```

Or if you want to avoid exception from the first approach if dictionary does not have a key

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> entityDetails;
if (EntityCollection.TryGetValue(entityId, out entityDetails))
{
}
```